# adding/editing data inside a hidden NTFS partition

Tags: partitioning, ntfs, file-permissions

I have a bootable USB stick that we use for imaging machines. Which has 2 Partitions in it.

1. Bootable MS-DOS (FAT 32) - Can edit etc
2. NTFS - Can't touch, can only read

The problem I have is that I can't edit the NTFS partition which houses the .tib files for the images.

I've tried this in both OSX and Windows 7.

The NTFS Partition appears to have read only rights which I can't seem to overcome even with sudo and chmod commands.

Also the NTFS partition is hidden on W7 so I can't even copy the files across and reformat it, back to NTFS (have tried finding it using diskpart but with no joy.

Any help much appreciated.

FYI The stick can't be formatted and neither can the DATA partition as I need all the information on both partitions.

Any help much appreciated

Comment: have you tried accessing it from a windows system? In general, you want to handle NTFS permissions in the volumes Mount command when you use it on linux, and when correctly mounted, will grant 777 access to the files. Sudo/Chmod willnot/cannot change permissions on items in a volume when the mount specifies things like readonly or uid=>permissions mappings. chmod cannot be used on NTFS volumes at all (nor can chown).

Comment: @FrankThomas yes W7 = Windows 7 but the Partition is hidden as specified.

Comment: have you tried this approach with diskpart? http://outrospective.org/wordpress/2009/03/easily-unhide-an-ntfs-partition-with-included-windows-tools/

Comment: yeah I have still no joy (forgot to mention that will update it above ty)